# sssd / ad no ssh login after migration debian 8 => 9: Access denied for user xxx: 4 (System error)

Tags: debian, sssd

After migration form debian jessie to stretch - login over ssh fails for Ad users, also su to AD user (sssd env) fails. Any hints?

Log lines:

```
Jun 20 12:48:57 myhost sshd[1736]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user testuser: 4 (System error)
Jun 20 12:48:57 myhost sshd[1736]: fatal: Access denied for user testuser by PAM account configuration [preauth] 
Jun 20 12:49:09 myhost su[1776]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=service uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=service rhost=  user=testuser
Jun 20 12:49:10 myhost su[1776]: pam_sss(su:auth): authentication success; logname=service uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=service rhost= user=testuser
Jun 20 12:49:10 myhost su[1776]: pam_sss(su:account): Access denied for user testuser: 4 (Systemfehler)
Jun 20 12:49:10 myhost su[1776]: pam_acct_mgmt: System error
Jun 20 12:49:10 myhost su[1776]: FAILED su for testuser by service
Jun 20 12:49:10 myhost su[1776]: - /dev/pts/1 service:testuser
```

Comment: Found solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1572908

Comment: Do you want to provide the solution here, as an Answer to your question?

Comment: @jeff-schaller: I made a copy in the Answer section. Hopefully this the right way you mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration file /etc/sssd/sssd.conf needs the following entry.

```
[domain/your.domain]
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```

I found the solution at the [Ubuntu sssd bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sssd/+bug/1572908)